# What is producing this blank page before the title?

Tags: memoir, titles, blank-page

After compiling the code below, I get a blank first page in my output (which is undesirable). I have no idea why I'm getting this blank page. Can someone help?

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany,a5paper,14pt]{memoir}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\fixpdflayout

% Chapter style
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50 pt}%
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
\bfseries\Huge
\ifnum \value{secnumdepth}>1 
\if@mainmatter\thechapter.\ \fi%
\fi
#1\par\nobreak\vspace{40 pt}}}

% Title style

\newlength\drop
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
  \hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
  \rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax}%
  \hspace*{0.05\textwidth}% 
  \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{%
    \vbox{%
      \vspace{\drop}
      {\Huge\bfseries\raggedright\@title\par}\vskip2.37\baselineskip
      {\Large\@author\par}
      \vspace{0.5\textheight}
    }% end of vbox
  }% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}

\makeatother

\title{Seguir adiante}
\author{Jos\'e Rodrigues}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\titleGM
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: provide a _complete_ example which shows the behaviour and not only fragtments.

Comment: I just compile your .tex (adding `\begin{document}...`) and I don't have the blank page...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the entire thing, the code is all there now. I deleted the auxuliary files and recompiled. The blank page before the title still appears.

Comment: The `\titleGM` design is too tall for the the textblock, see the log file.

Comment: You have *at least* two baseline skips before the rule starts. In your document `\the\dimexpr2\baselineskip\relax` should print `35pt`. As such, you should remove *at least* `35pt` from `\textheight` for the `\rule` to fit.

Comment: Thanks; the first time I saw the log file I took the underfull and overfull boxes for text problems, but it is fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax}%
```

is too tall to fit into the page.  The simplest thing would be to shorten is a bit

```
\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-35pt\relax}%
```